# R table not outputting results within for loop

Tags: r

I am just trying to loop over my columns and print out the count of unique values for further processing - but getting not output. This should be simple but I am not getting any output. Here is a simplified version of my code. Is there something glaringly obviously missing as I suspect

```
for (i in 1:length(mydata)) {
 (table(mydata[,i]))
}
```

Comment: Inside a loop or inside a function you must use `print(.)`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean using `apply`?

```
> x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:4, "Age" = c(21,15,56,15), "Name" = 
c("John","Dora","John","Dora"))
> apply(x,2,function(x) unique(x))
$SN
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4"

$Age
[1] "21" "15" "56"

$Name
[1] "John" "Dora"
```

You can also count the uniques like this:

```
> apply(x,2,function(x) length(unique(x)))
  SN  Age Name 
   4    3    2
```

Comment: This is certainly useful and good code but a little too much for my needs. As an above comment said, I simply forget to add in 'print'!  But thanks for the input, I might give that a try another time.